# django user login view

Tags: django, authentication, django-views

I want to place a "login" field in every page. I looked some examples about authentication in django and all of them creates a new login page and uses django.contrib.auth.views.login . 
However, I want to use some parts of this view. So how can i create a view that uses also django auth ?

p.s.: if it's not clear let me know, cause I'm kinda lost and don't know how to ask =)

Answer (score 0):

At first try take a look here https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/ 
It is ready done registration/login solution, you can create some template for login and after this include to your pages using include syntax http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include